# How to filter or remove the "title" attribute from category links

Tags: theme-development

I'm placing a list of category links with this code:

```
<div><h2>Categories List</h2>
    <ul>
    <?php          
        function my_cat_title($category_description,$category){
            return '';
        }

        $cat_args = array('orderby' => 'name');
        $cat_args['title_li'] = '';
        $cat_args['exclude_tree'] = 1;
        $cat_args['use_desc_for_title'] = 1;
        add_filter('category_description','my_cat_title');
        wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));
        remove_filter('category_description','my_cat_title');

        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, each of the links has a title attribute like 'title="View all posts filed under x"'

How can I remove the title attribute altogether?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `category_description` filter hook you can replace the title attribute for example:

```
function my_cat_title($category_description,$category){
   return '';
}
add_filter('category_description','my_cat_title');
$cat_args = array('orderby' => 'name');
$cat_args['title_li'] = '';
$cat_args['exclude_tree'] = my_cat();
wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));
remove_filter('category_description','my_cat_title');
```

Comment: Hmm, its not working for me :-( I've updated my question with the revised code. I'm still getting a title attribute on the links